# Getting validation error 'is_staff': ["'true' value must be either True or False."] while implementing SSO using djangosaml2

Tags: django, postgresql, single-sign-on, python-3.6, saml-2.0

I tried to implement SSO for my Django project.
when I tried to login form SP ('/sso/login') I got the correct response from my IDP but on SP side 'sso/acs' it throwing a validation error.

```
{'is_superuser': ["'true' value must be either True or False."], 'is_staff': ["'true' value must be either True or False."]}
```

When I removed is_staff and is_superuser from SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING.
SSO is working.
Project packages -
django 1.11,
postgress,
djangosaml2idp 0.5.0,  for IDP
djangosaml2 0.17.2     for SP

```
My setting for SP: 
SAML_USE_NAME_ID_AS_USERNAME = True
SAML_DJANGO_USER_MAIN_ATTRIBUTE = 'email'
SAML_DJANGO_USER_MAIN_ATTRIBUTE_LOOKUP = '__iexact'
SAML_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USER = False
SAML_LOGOUT_REQUEST_PREFERRED_BINDING = saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST

SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
    # SAML : DJANGO
    # Must also be present in attribute-maps!
    'email': ('email', ),
    'username': ('username', ),
    'account_id': ('account_id', ),
    'is_staff': ('is_staff', ),
    'is_superuser':  ('is_superuser', ),
}
```

**Error Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangosaml2/views.py", line 316, in assertion_consumer_service
    create_unknown_user=create_unknown_user)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangosaml2/backends.py", line 107, in authenticate
    create_unknown_user, main_attribute, attributes, attribute_mapping)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangosaml2/backends.py", line 154, in get_saml2_user
    return self._get_saml2_user(main_attribute, attributes, attribute_mapping)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangosaml2/backends.py", line 188, in _get_saml2_user
    user = self.update_user(user, attributes, attribute_mapping)
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djangosaml2/backends.py", line 250, in update_user
    user.save()
  File "/Users/lite/projects/djangosaml2/sample-sp/sp/models.py", line 105, in save
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/lite/Virtual_Envs/spEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1203, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'is_superuser': ["'true' value must be either True or False."], 'is_staff': ["'true' value must be either True or False."]}
```

I tried with different DBs and with or without overriding Django user model.
when I tried with default (auth.models) User model sso is working with Postgres and sqlite backend but when I override the User model for my custom user model it throwing above error. 
I think on SP is not typecasting IDP response, it just parsing and passing all attributes as strings and while saving on DB it causing a validation error. but why it is working with the default Django User model ?

**Application User model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True,)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=123, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def clean(self):
        errors = {}
        users = get_user_model().objects.filter(username__iexact=self.username)
        if len(users) > 1:
            errors.setdefault('username', []).append(f'{self.username} not available')
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, seems like this is something to do with `djangosaml2idp` implementation.

From the example code in the source, you should add the following code in the User app view.py file (or in the main project folder, if you didn't customize the User model).

```
@receiver(pre_user_save, sender=User)
def custom_update_user(sender, instance, attributes, user_modified, **kargs):
    """ Default behaviour does not play nice with booleans encoded in SAML as u'true'/u'false'.
        This will convert those attributes to real booleans when saving.
    """
    for k, v in attributes.items():
        u = set.intersection(set(v), set([u'true', u'false']))
        if u:
            setattr(instance, k, u.pop() == u'true')
    return True
```

Source:
[custom_update_user](https://github.com/OTA-Insight/djangosaml2idp/blob/master/example_setup/sp/sp/views.py#L25)